# gdal_warp cannot specify target extents

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, gdalwarp

This is related to this previous [post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/320794/how-to-use-gdal-warp-with-modified-crop-to-cutline/321305#321305).

As was trying to implement the said answer and inserting it to my code, but the code doesn't seem to work.

```
#importing all the necessary modules
import os, glob, gdal
from subprocess import call
#call(["ls", "-l"]) #calling the "ls -l" command in linux 

shp = "/home/brent/Documents/Hansen_new_data/Palawan_only.shp"

os.chdir("/home/brent/Documents/Hansen_new_data/New_data/10_110/NAMRIA_based")
extent = ("116.928337 7.506939 120.000087 10.000189")
for rname in glob.glob("*AMRIA_gain_10N_110E.tif"): #iterate through the files using glob.glob
    raster = os.path.join("/home/brent/Documents/Hansen_new_data/New_data/10_110/NAMRIA_based", rname) #join the shp file name to a new file path name
    raster2 = rname.replace("NAMRIA_gain_10N_110E","Palawan")
    outRaster =  os.path.join("/home/brent/Documents/Hansen_new_data/New_data/10_110/Province/gain/", raster2) #specifying the output raster new name
    warp = 'gdalwarp -te \'%s\' -cutline \'%s\' -crop_to_cutline -overwrite -co compress=LZW \'%s\' \'%s\'' % (extent, shp, raster, outRaster) #calling gdal warp, crop to cutline is specified here
    os.system(warp) #running gdalwarp, uncomment this line to run
```

Comment: have you tried without the barckets around the extent values ? It does not seem necessary.extent should simply be a string

Comment: yes, I removed it but it says now that the syntax is invalid.

Comment: By the way I'm running the QGIS 3.6 (latest) version.