# gdalwarp reprojection to 3857: how to remove added background?

Tags: gdal, gdalwarp

I'm reprojecting a tif from Lambert Azimuthal Equal Area to EPSG:3857 using gdalwarp. How can I remove the background that is added by the reprojection, outside of the extents of my data ? In the image below, the data of interest is within the white rectangle.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you haven't included your code it's a bit ambiguous. You can set the extents of your destination_raster to the original by using `-te` amongst your gdalwarp variables. Please refer [to this question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/321305/103942).

The other thing that I'm suspected of is to use [gdalwarp nodata](https://gdal.org/programs/gdalwarp.html) `-srcnodata` and `dstnodata` as it helps the visualizer to make the background invisible.